# Por que o console do Chrome retorna 8 quando digito 010?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Vocês saberiam me dizer porque quando eu digito no console `010` e aperto enter ele me retorna `8` ? e se digito `0100` ele me retorna `64`.

Comment: Isso acontece em várias linguagens, essas duas perguntas do programmers explicam o pq como nas respostas abaixo e a origem disso. [why do so manylanguages treat numbers starting with 0 as octal](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224132/why-do-so-many-languages-treat-numbers-starting-with-0-as-octal) e [where-are-octals-useful](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/where-are-octals-useful)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quando o Chrome interpreta um número começando com o caractere `0` ele o faz como sendo um octal.

A representação octal do número 8 (decimal) é `010`, e a representação octal do número 64 (decimal) é `0100`.

### O que é representação octal

É um sistema de numeração, tal como existe o decimal, o hexadecimal, só que na base 8.
Os outros sistemas de numeração também podem ter caracteres especiais para representá-los.

- binário: base 2 (não tem representação)
- **octal:** base 8 (representado começando o número por `0`)
- decimal: base 10 (representado começando com qualquer número diferente de `0`)
- hexadecimal: base 16 (pode ser representado iniciando-se com `0x`)

### Como é feita a conversão

A conversão mais complicada são as entre octal/decimal, pois as bases não são múltiplas entre si.

Código para exemplificar como funciona a conversão (note que o javascript já fornece métodos capazes de fazer essas conversões, o meu intuito é de mostrar o funcionamento):

**[De octal para decimal](http://jsfiddle.net/x5xU4/)**

```
function ConverterOctalParaNumero(txt)
{
    var result = 0, mul = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){
        var ch = txt[txt.length - i - 1];
        result += ch * mul;
        mul *= 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**[De decimal para octal](http://jsfiddle.net/G26z8/)**

```
function ConverterNumeroParaOctal(num)
{
    var result = "";
    while (num > 0){
        result = "01234567"[num % 8] + result;
        num = Math.floor(num / 8);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**O navegador está fazendo uma conversão de DECIMAL para OCTAL**

`Decimal` para `octal`: **10** é **8**; **100** é **64**; **45** é **55**.

E por ai vai. Lembrando que `010` é equivalente a `10`, assim como `0100` é igual a `100`.

---

**Como fazer um calculo de Decimal para Octal?**

**1985 / 8**

*385*   **248 / 8**

*65*    *08*   **31 / 8**

**1    0    7   3**

1 é resto da divisão. MOD
0 é resto da divisão. MOD
7 é resto da divisão. MOD
3 é o resultado da divisão. /

Nesse exemplo você deve ler o número de trás para frente. 3701 a conversão de decimal para binário é semelhante.

[Wikipedia Conversões - Octal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convers%C3%A3o_entre_sistemas_num%C3%A9ricos#Convers.C3.A3o_de_Octal_para_Decimal)