# Converter Data gerada em C# para formato ISO no Javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Olá, estou fazendo um website onde uso uma API construída em C#. O meu problema
é que quando recebo uma data do servidor, ele me manda nesse formato:

```
[{
    "dataLiberacao":"\/Date(928160400000-0300)\/",
    "dataReg":"\/Date(928160400000-0300)\/",
    "id":2147483647,
    "maquina":"Conteúdo da cadeia de caracteres",
    "status":true,
    "versao":"Conteúdo da cadeia de caracteres"
}]
```

Preciso saber como posso converter isso em um formato comum para o Javascript.

**NOTA:** Já tentei com o pessoal da API para que me enviassem isso em string mas, infelizmente não irão mudar o projeto por isso...

Comment: Pode usar alguma biblioteca jQuery como momentjs ?

Comment: poder pode, mas quanto menos lib's melhor né rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baixe [***momentjs***](http://momentjs.com/) que é uma biblioteca [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), que trabalha com diversos formatos de datas e várias funções:

```
moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/").format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

```js
var data = moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/").format('DD/MM/YYYY'); 
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment-with-locales.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

No seu caso seria algo:

```
moment(dataLiberacao).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

---

**Uma outra maneira:**

Com [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) e [`new Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
var data = eval('new Date(1198908717056-0700)');
console.log(data.toLocaleString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

<sub>As duas maneiras são funcionais, o [***momentjs***](http://momentjs.com/) é uma biblioteca pequena não atrapalha o carregamento da página e como já foi até relatado é muito estável, mas, também tem a outra forma que pode solucionar seu problema sem um `lib` externa.</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)
- [Moment.js Documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/)
- [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)
- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: @LeandroLUK, no amigo Virgilio respondeu com a lib que te falei acima, ela é bem estável e está a anos ai =]

Comment: certo, sinceramente não queria incluir mais um script na página, preferia criar uma "micro-função" pra isso do que ter inúmeras outras que não vou usar mas já resolve meu caso rs

Comment: @LeandroLUK você agora tem duas opções uma com um mini-framework javascript de 20k e o outro com duas linhas e o comando `eval` com `new Date`. Veja qual é a melhor para você .

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro temos que entender o que é este formato, pois dependendo do que você precisar (ou de como tratá-lo), pode dar resultados diferentes. Não parece haver um "nome oficial", mas informalmente é conhecido como [Microsoft JSON Date](https://davidsekar.com/javascript/converting-json-date-string-date-to-date-object).

<sup>[Pessoalmente](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2020-01-18/meu-json-retornou-a-data-date-1555375534143-0300-o-que-eu-faco), acho que é um dos piores e mais confusos formatos de data já criados, mas enfim...</sup>

Basicamente, ele é composto de duas partes: um [*Unix timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) em milissegundos e um [*offset*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info#:%7E:text=Diferen%C3%A7as%20entre%20timezone%20e%20offset) (a diferença em relação a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) - ou seja: `/Date(timestamp + offset)/`.

Portanto, a primeira parte (o timestamp) refere-se à quantidade de milissegundos que se passaram desde o Unix Epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z` - 1 de janeiro de 1970 à meia-noite em UTC). E o offset indica a diferença com relação a UTC.

Então se tivermos `/Date(928160400000-0300)/`, o timestamp `928160400000` corresponde a `1999-05-31T14:20:00.000Z` (31 de maio de 1999, às 14:20 em **UTC**). Mas se aplicarmos o offset `-0300` (3 horas antes de UTC), o resultado será `1999-05-31T11:20:00.000-03:00` (31 de maio de 1999, às **11:20**).

Repare que neste caso o dia não mudou (somente o horário), mas tem casos em que o dia pode mudar. Por exemplo, se o timestamp fosse `928112400000`: isso corresponde a 31/05/1999 às 01:00 em UTC, mas se aplicarmos o offset `-0300`, corresponderá a **30**/05/1999 às 22:00.

**Então o primeiro ponto é decidir se o offset deverá ser levado em conta (ou ignorado) ao formatar o resultado final.** Pois como já vimos, tanto a data quanto a hora podem ser diferentes em cada caso.

Enfim, nos comentários também foi citada a preocupação em não usar uma biblioteca externa, então uma maneira de obter a data seria extrair o timestamp e o offset da string, separadamente:

```js
let regex = /Date\((\d+)([-+]\d{4})?\)/;
let match = regex.exec('/Date(928160400000-0300)/');
// obtém o timestamp e cria a data
let data = new Date(parseInt(match[1]));

// ler o offset (caso não exista, estou assumindo que é UTC - ou seja, offset zero)
let offset = match[2] || '+0000';

// *** Para ver como formatar a data, e também o que fazer com o offset,
// leia o restante da resposta :-) ***
```

---

## Formato de saída

No título da pergunta é citado o "formato ISO", embora na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166795/112052) tenha sido gerado o formato "dd/mm/aaaa". Se o "formato ISO" que você se refere for aquele definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), então deveria ser algo como "aaaa-mm-ddThh:mm:ss" (ou apenas "aaaa-mm-dd" - a norma permite essas variações, mas enfim, não ficou claro qual é o formato desejado).

De qualquer forma, independente do formato, ainda temos o problema de definir se o offset será ou não levado em consideração. Pois como já vimos, o resultado pode ser diferente (não só o horário, mas também a data).

#### Ignorando o offset

Uma opção seria usar o [método `toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), mas vale lembrar que ele sempre retorna a data e hora em UTC (ou seja, vai ignorar completamente o offset). Outra opção é usar [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), que usa o timezone que estiver configurado no browser (então também ignora o offset), além de não necessariamente retornar no "formato ISO" (**mas vale lembrar que na verdade ele usará o formato associado ao *locale default***, que geralmente corresponde às configurações de idioma do browser).

Você também pode informar um *locale* específico e um timezone qualquer para `toLocaleString`. Exemplo:

```js
console.log(data.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo' }));
```

Mas como já dito, **o formato não será necessariamente "ISO"**, e sim o que está associado ao *locale* informado (no exemplo acima, `pt-BR` é o português do Brasil, que resulta em "dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"). Se quiser algum outro formato específico, você poderia usar os *getters* (`getHours()`, `getMonth()`, etc) e montar a string manualmente - lembrando que os *getters* retornam os valores de acordo com o timezone do browser.

#### Considerando o offset

Infelizmente o JavaScript não fornece opções para formatar em um determinado formato **e ao mesmo tempo** manter um offset específico (que não seja UTC ou o timezone configurado no browser). Isso já foi discutido em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052) - inclusive, você pode ver a [seção "Gambiarra" desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052) (e principalmente, leia os poréns antes de utilizá-la).

Sei que você não queria adicionar uma lib, mas com Moment.js daria para preservar o offset facilmente, usando [`parseZone`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/):

```js
let data = moment.parseZone("/Date(928160400000-0300)/");
console.log(data.format()); // 1999-05-31T11:20:00-03:00

// se quiser, pode converter para Date
let d = data.toDate();
// mas aí perde o offset, e as opções são as já informadas acima
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 1999-05-31T14:20:00.000Z
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

<sup>Entendo a preocupação de adicionar uma lib gigante só para usar uma única e pequena parte, mas tem casos em que vale a pena. Mesmo que o Moment.js esteja sendo [encerrado](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), talvez ainda seja uma alternativa (no caso de precisar de um offset específico, é uma alternativa melhor que a gambiarra mencionada acima). Outra solução é ver as [libs alternativas sugeridas pela própria equipe do Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/).</sup>

---

## Comentário sobre a solução sem lib da outra resposta

A outra resposta sugeriu usar `eval('new Date(1198908717056-0700)');`. Sem entrar no mérito de discutir o uso de `eval` (que já foi amplamente debatido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/112052)), o problema aqui é outro.

Este código é equivalente a executar `new Date(1198908717056-0700)`. Repare que o argumento passado para o construtor de `Date` é um número. Sim, a expressão `1198908717056-0700` na verdade corresponde a dois números sendo subtraídos: `1198908717056` e `0700` (e como este é um literal que começa com zero, na verdade [é interpretado como um número na base 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10701/112052), portanto essa expressão equivale a `1198908717056 - 448`, ou seja, `1198908716608`).

**Isso resulta em um instante (um valor de timestamp) diferente do original**, veja:

```js
// timestamp original: 1198908717056
console.log(new Date(1198908717056).toISOString());      // 2007-12-29T06:11:57.056Z

// com "offset" (na verdade, está subtraindo 0700 do timestamp)
// e 0700 é tratado com um valor na base 8, que corresponde a 448 em decimal
console.log(new Date(1198908717056-0700).toISOString()); // 2007-12-29T06:11:56.608Z

// portanto, é o mesmo que usar o timestamp 1198908716608
console.log(new Date(1198908716608).toISOString());      // 2007-12-29T06:11:56.608Z

// ou seja, este eval está errado, pois modifica o timestamp
var data = eval('new Date(1198908717056-0700)');
console.log(data.toISOString());                         // 2007-12-29T06:11:56.608Z
```

Repare como o timestamp `1198908717056` equivale ao horário `06:11:57.056`, e ao subtrair o "offset" (que já vimos que não é o offset), resulta em `06:11:56.608`. O horário está diferente justamente porque foi feita a subtração. O `-0700` neste caso não é o offset, é um número que está sendo subtraído do timestamp.

E neste caso não adianta passar a string `"/Date(928160400000-0300)/"` para o construtor de `Date`, pois não será criada uma data válida. O jeito seria extrair o timestamp e o offset (como feito acima), e aí decidir como formatar (se usa um *locale*/timezone específico, se ignora o offset ou usa a "gambiarra", se delega para uma lib, etc).

---

> Para saber mais sobre o `Date` do Javascript, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).