# Por que 16 é igual a 020 no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, octal

Estava comparando CPF's quando cheguei a seguinte expressão:

```js
if(16 == 020){
    console.log(true)
}else{
    console.log(false)
}
```

O resultado dessa expressão é `true`, gostaria de entender o porquê.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Por que o console do Chrome retorna 8 quando digito 010?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10701/5878) | [Números com inicio zero em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117657/5878) | [O que são números de notação Decimal, Hexadecimal e Octal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47854/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tem uma resposta minha num desses links que eu nem me lembrava mais. Obrigado por me lembrar dela :)

Answer (score 11):

O número `020` está sendo interpretado como octal - ou seja, base 8, utilizando os dígitos `0` a `7` para se representar os valores. Em JavaScript, valores literais iniciados com zero são [interpretados como octais](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-OctalIntegerLiteral), [exceto no modo estrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2746/quando-por-que-e-como-utilizar-a-diretiva-use-strict-em-javascript/3752#3752) da linguagem. `020` em octal representa `16` na base 10.

Uma outra notação possível na linguagem para octais literais é com o prefixo `0o` ou `0O` (zero-oh). Assim, o valor decimal 16 também pode ser representado como `0o20` ou `0O20`.

Comment: Interessante salientar que é considerado octal apenas se for um valor octal válido. Quando inválido, permanece como decimal: `089` é o próprio decimal 89. Somente utilizando a notação com a letra O, `0o89`, que dá erro

Comment: Bem observado. Um pouco perigoso confiar no zero à esquerda, portanto. Por isso até que essa sintaxe é desligada no strict mode.